# Inserting ArrayLists into ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't really know how to ask this without creating confusion, but I'll try.

In my Swing application I want to add an `ArrayList` to an `ArrayList` and then `clear();` the second ArrayList without all the data being lost.

Here's an example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aList1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> aList2 = new ArrayList<>();
aList2.add("Object 1");
aList2.add("Object 2");
aList1.add(aList2);
aList2.clear();
System.out.println(aList1);
```

But then all the data is lost and aList1 is empty. I assume this is because I add the `ArrayList` as `ArrayList` and not as values. Is it possible to save the data in aList1 while deleting it from `aList2`, thus making space for future use.

Comment: Hint: start reading javadocs for the library calls you are using. Most collections have an **addAll()** method for example. In your code, you are adding the LIST as LIST to another LIST. Then you wipe that list you added, you your final list only contains one EMPTY list.

Comment: What if you do: `aList1.add((ArrayList<String>) aList2.clone());`

Comment: +1 on the clone function. ArrayList implements Cloneable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I would prefer `List1.add(new ArrayList<>(aList2));` over clone

Comment: @Kartic that's also a good one

Comment: I guess if your list holds only String, clone would be faster, but it's absolutely your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Create new ArrayList From the ArrayList you want to add.

Here is it

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aList1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> aList2 = new ArrayList<>();
   aList2.add("Object 1");
   aList2.add("Object 2");
   aList1.add(new ArrayList(aList2));
   aList2.clear();
   System.out.println(aList1);
```

Comment: You're the man! Thanks, that was exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description step by step of your code:

```
// Define a list of lists named aList1 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> aList1 = new ArrayList<>();

// Define a list named aList2
ArrayList<String> aList2 = new ArrayList<>();

// Add an element to aList2
aList2.add("Object 1");

// Add an element to aList2
aList2.add("Object 2");


// Add aList2 to aList1
aList1.add(aList2);

// Empty aList2
aList2.clear();

// Print aList1. Now aList1 is not empty. Is a list containing just
// one list of size 0.
System.out.println(aList1);
```

As shown step by step. At the end of the process **`aList1` is not empty**.
**It contains just one empty list**.

Clearing `aList2` remove all elements inside `aList2`, because `aList2` is the same list in position 0 of `aList1` at the end `aList1.get(0)` exists and is the empty list pointed also by `aList2`.

Answer (score 0):

consider using a list for coping as backup the list you are clearing..

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<List<String>> aList1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    final List<String> aList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> aList3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    aList2.add("Object 1");
    aList2.add("Object 2");
    aList3.addAll(aList2);
    aList1.add(aList2);
    aList1.add(aList3);
    aList2.clear();
    System.out.println(aList1);
}
```